# How can I access the event which matrix throws when we invite a user to chat?

Tags: react-native, matrix-org

I am trying to accept an invite sent from a user on other side but I am not able to catch the event which matrix throws when we invite a user from other side.

I have tried to spot the event but could not and went through the documentation but have not found any clue.

Comment: Could you provide more information? I don't really understood what you're working on and exactly fails here. Are you speaking of react-native-matrix-sdk here? If so then you have to point this exactly in your question.

Comment: Yes in react native I have let the user join a room when someone invites in a room

Comment: Did you work this out at all please? I think we're trying to do the same (in Vue using the js-sdk). For user 1 we perform a `client.createRoom` and supply the `invite` attribute with user 2's Matrix ID. Next time user 2 comes to the app we want to auto-accept the invite as it is a closed system and all parties involved have privileges to message each other that are governed outside of Matrix. It isn't feasible nor sensible to create rooms via the server/bot for every combination of users to DM each other and finding membership events of type 'invite' that have not been accepted is eluding us